# jQuery get last visited url in ajax page

Tags: jquery

I am creating a web app using ajax and I am facing a problem in getting the last visited URL so that I can reload the content when someone presses back button on browser.

Suppose I am on http://example.com and then I navigated to http://example.com/#hello-world and navigated to http://example.com/#using-custom-function.

It works well when we go forward but when the user clicks on the back button on the browser then the page doesn't loads the content but the URL changes.

I have tried hash change but that also doesn't help as it reloads the page for forward and backward request also.

I am wondering if there is a solution to this.

Here is my ajax function,

```
function get_gallery_artworks(arguments,data,media,type,page,callback_function, gal_ids){

     /*Masking*/
    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = jQuery('window').height();
    var maskWidth = jQuery('window').width();

    var loaderWidth = maskWidth/2;

    var overlay_id = 'overlay-div';

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    jQuery('.loader-image').css({
        'left':loaderWidth,
        'top':maskHeight
    });
    jQuery('.overlay').css({
        'opacity':0,
        'height':jQuery(document).height(),
        'width':jQuery(window).width()
    });

    //transition effect     
    jQuery('.overlay').fadeIn(1000);    
    jQuery('.overlay').fadeTo("slow",0.8);


     var loader_height = ((jQuery(document).height())/4);
     var loader_width =  ((jQuery(window).width())/2);
    jQuery('#'+overlay_id).css('left', loader_width);
    jQuery('#'+overlay_id).css('top', loader_height);

    jQuery('#'+overlay_id).css('display',  'block');//alert('#'+id);
    jQuery('#'+overlay_id).css('padding',  '0px 0px 15px 15px');

    //transition effect
    jQuery(overlay_id).fadeIn(2000); 
    var data_str = arguments;

    window.location.hash = 'gallery='+data_str;

    var data_arr = data_str.split("_");  
    collection_id = data_arr['0']; 
    artist_id = data_arr['1'];
    artwork_id = data_arr['2']; 

    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : ajax_url,
        data : {
            collection_id:collection_id, 
            artwork_id:artwork_id, 
            artist_id:artist_id, 
            media:media, 
            type:type,
            callback:callback_function,
            navigation:jQuery('.gs-top-navigation').html(),
            gspage:page,
            data : '',//data_obj
            gal_ids : gal_ids
        },   
        success: function(result) { 

            jQuery('.overlay').hide();  
            jQuery('.window').hide();
            jQuery('.gs-content').html(result);
            window.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        window.document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
            jQuery('.overlay').hide();  
            jQuery('.window').hide();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Yes there is a solution for it.. But what have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: Here is what i have done so far.

`jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
 window.location.reload(true);
});`


But it reloads the page always

Comment: you could try to use a jquery plugin solution [jQuery hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) allows you to perform actions/functions on url hashchange

Comment: @milkshake i have tried that and i just want to do it for backward requests like the urls in history

Comment: What does your AJAX function look like? Does it load from the URL? Can you show that bit?

Comment: Are you writing a jQuery mobile app?

Comment: Jo its for all devices

Comment: @NirmalRam it should work for both forward and backward requests, but you may have to call it on pageload as well as hash change for it to work going backwords, please provide some example code.

Comment: I figured out it but if anyone can tell me how can i get the last url from the history then that would be nice

Comment: You could use `document.referrer` to get the previous page. And please share the solution here in Answers so that it could help someone else looking for a similar solution.

Comment: document.referrer wouldn't work for ajax url's it would work only for normal url so i need something so that i can use it with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using

```
jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  jQuery("body").load(location.href+' body');
});
```

But there one issue though i need it to call when the url is previous url like `location.href==previous url` then i need to run the above